# Why won't Delta.Patch update a byte array to a null value?

Tags: c#, .net, odata

My object model has a byte array for storing an image. When I try to update this byte array to a new value via [Delta.Patch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/jj890126(v%3Dvs.118)), it works just fine, but when I try to update it to null, it fails.

This is the line of code I'm looking at is

`update.Patch(entity);`

If I look at the `update` object, I can see that `update.ChangedProperties` includes my image property, so it knows it's aware that it should be updated. I can also see that `update._instance` contains the instance of the object which has a null value for the image field, and I can use Fiddler to see that the changed value is being sent up as null.

But when I look at the `entity` object after calling `.Patch` when the new value is supposed to be null, the byte array is not updated. Other updates in the Delta get updated correctly, but not this byte array.

What could be causing this? I'm still new to OData, and am not sure if I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: I am on it. I have a lead, but I need to know which version of OData nuget package are you using and for which platform?

Comment: Sorry, just saw this now. Version is Microsoft.AspNet.OData, Version=7.1.0.21120

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reviewed source code of OData([WebAPI version](https://github.com/OData/WebApi)) and (probably) found core issue. Issue also apply to ASP.NET Core version as it is shared code base with ASP.NET WebAPI.

**Issue**

You call `Patch(TStructuralType original)` method which calls `CopyChangedValues(TStructuralType original)` method. Both are public members of [`Delta<T>` class](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Shared/DeltaOfTStructuralType.cs)

```
public void Patch(TStructuralType original)
{
    CopyChangedValues(original);
}
```

Inside `CopyChangedValues(TStructuralType original)` method is a piece of code that handles copying values to original instance. Code iterates through [`PropertyAccessor<TStructuralType>`](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Shared/PropertyAccessor.cs) array and calls `Copy(TStructuralType from, TStructuralType to)` method.

```
// For regular non-structural properties at current level.
PropertyAccessor<TStructuralType>[] propertiesToCopy =
                this._changedProperties.Select(s => _allProperties[s]).ToArray();
foreach (PropertyAccessor<TStructuralType> propertyToCopy in propertiesToCopy)
{
    propertyToCopy.Copy(_instance, original);
}
```

Inside `Copy(TStructuralType from, TStructuralType to)` implemented in `PropertyAccessor<TStructuralType>` you'll find call to abstract `SetValue(TStructuralType instance, object value)`.

```
public void Copy(TStructuralType from, TStructuralType to)
{
    if (from == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("from");
    }
    if (to == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("to");
    }
    SetValue(to, GetValue(from));
}
```

This method is implemented by [`FastPropertyAccessor<TStructuralType>`](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/release/src/Microsoft.AspNet.OData.Shared/FastPropertyAccessor.cs) class.

```
public override void SetValue(TStructuralType instance, object value)
{
    if (instance == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("instance");
    }

    if (_isCollection)
    {
        DeserializationHelpers.SetCollectionProperty(instance, _property.Name, edmPropertyType: null,
            value: value, clearCollection: true);
    }
    else
    {
        _setter(instance, value);
    }
}
```

Important line of code is `if (_isCollection)`. This boolean flag is set in the constructor and calls `IsCollection()` static method in [`TypeHelper`](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/release/src/System.Web.OData/OData/TypeHelper.cs) class.

```
public FastPropertyAccessor(PropertyInfo property)
    : base(property)
{
    _property = property;
    _isCollection = TypeHelper.IsCollection(property.PropertyType);

    if (!_isCollection)
    {
        _setter = PropertyHelper.MakeFastPropertySetter<TStructuralType>(property);
    }
    _getter = PropertyHelper.MakeFastPropertyGetter(property);
}
```

In `IsCollection(Type clrType)` we traverse call to `IsCollection(this Type type, out Type elementType)`.

```
public static bool IsCollection(Type clrType)
{
    Type elementType;
    return TypeHelper.IsCollection(clrType, out elementType);
}
```

Here are important lines following `// see if this type should be ignored.` comment(which is weird one and may indicate someone forgot to finish what he has started) where only `string`(`char[]`) are excluded. Other arrays (including `byte[]`) skips to following code, that evaluates byte[](and any other array type) positively as those types are implementing `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

```
public static bool IsCollection(Type clrType, out Type elementType)
{
    if (clrType == null)
    {
        throw Error.ArgumentNull("clrType");
    }

    elementType = clrType;

    // see if this type should be ignored.
    if (clrType == typeof(string))
    {
        return false;
    }

    Type collectionInterface
        = clrType.GetInterfaces()
            .Union(new[] { clrType })
            .FirstOrDefault(
                t => TypeHelper.IsGenericType(t)
                        && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));

    if (collectionInterface != null)
    {
        elementType = collectionInterface.GetGenericArguments().Single();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

If we jump back to `SetValue(TEntityType entity, object value)` method implementation we end up calling `DeserializationHelpers.SetCollectionProperty(entity, _property.Name, edmPropertyType: null, value: value, clearCollection: true);` in [`DeserializationHelpers`](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/blob/release/src/System.Web.OData/OData/Formatter/Deserialization/DeserializationHelpers.cs) class.

```
if (_isCollection)
{
    DeserializationHelpers.SetCollectionProperty(instance, _property.Name, edmPropertyType: null,
        value: value, clearCollection: true);
}
```

It is clear that implementation of this method is very defensive and avoids throwing exception in case value of collection is `null`. First line of the method is `if (value != null)` and there is no `else` block or code after the code block to be executed. We can literally say, null values are ignored for every type implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, thus not set.

```
internal static void SetCollectionProperty(object resource, string propertyName,
    IEdmCollectionTypeReference edmPropertyType, object value, bool clearCollection)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        IEnumerable collection = value as IEnumerable;
        Contract.Assert(collection != null,
            "SetCollectionProperty is always passed the result of ODataFeedDeserializer or ODataCollectionDeserializer");

        Type resourceType = resource.GetType();
        Type propertyType = GetPropertyType(resource, propertyName);

        Type elementType;
        if (!TypeHelper.IsCollection(propertyType, out elementType))
        {
            string message = Error.Format(SRResources.PropertyIsNotCollection, propertyType.FullName, propertyName, resourceType.FullName);
            throw new SerializationException(message);
        }

        IEnumerable newCollection;
        if (CanSetProperty(resource, propertyName) &&
            CollectionDeserializationHelpers.TryCreateInstance(propertyType, edmPropertyType, elementType, out newCollection))
        {
            // settable collections
            collection.AddToCollection(newCollection, elementType, resourceType, propertyName, propertyType);
            if (propertyType.IsArray)
            {
                newCollection = CollectionDeserializationHelpers.ToArray(newCollection, elementType);
            }

            SetProperty(resource, propertyName, newCollection);
        }
        else
        {
            // get-only collections.
            newCollection = GetProperty(resource, propertyName) as IEnumerable;
            if (newCollection == null)
            {
                string message = Error.Format(SRResources.CannotAddToNullCollection, propertyName, resourceType.FullName);
                throw new SerializationException(message);
            }

            if (clearCollection)
            {
                newCollection.Clear(propertyName, resourceType);
            }

            collection.AddToCollection(newCollection, elementType, resourceType, propertyName, propertyType);
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Solution 1**

First possible solution is to create custom model binder and handle `null` values for `byte[]` returning empty byte array and adding `NullByteArrayModelBinder` class to model binders.

**Disclaimer: Didn't tested it, but should work.**

```
public class NullByteArrayModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder {
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext) {
        if(bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(byte[])) {
            return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext) ?? new byte[0];
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}
```

This approach have one downside. Consumers of the OData also need to handle empty array `array.Length > 0` everywhere where `array != null` check takes place now.

---

**Solution 2**

Second option is to customize serialization and deserialization.

Serialize: from empty `array` to `null` => `array.Length > 0 ? array : null;`

Deserialize: from `null` to empty `array`=> `array ?? new byte[0];`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed response! I am glad to hear it's not an issue with my code. Current solution I am using is if value is null before saving, replace it with an empty byte array. I'll look into your other solutions as well though :)